# How to store the GeoRegionValuePlot tiles in a .mx file?

Tags: geographics

I have a huge association of counties associated with some values. I am creating a GeoRegionValuePlot for this data. But every time I execute this the code in a fresh kernel, it always downloads the GeoGraphic tiles and this makes the plotting slow and time consuming.

Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
countries = 
  Entity["Country", #] & /@ {"UnitedStates", "Canada", "Mexico", 
    "Spain", "France", "Norway", "Egypt", "SaudiArabia", "Vietnam", 
    "Australia"};
values := RandomInteger[{1000, 9999}, 10];
data = AssociationThread[countries -> values];
GeoRegionValuePlot[data]
```

Is there a way to cache the downloaded tiles into .mx files that I can load everytime I run this code instead of downloading the tiles from the server?

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is use the [`GeoServer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoServer.html) option extend the `"CacheDuration"`.  The default duration is 1 day but can be increased to 7 days with the following.

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[
 data,
 GeoServer -> {Automatic, "Storage" -> {"CacheDuration" -> Quantity[7, "Days"]}}
 ]
```

There is also the undocumented `` GeoGraphics`TileData `` function but I have not looked too deep into how you would use that or reincorporate its result back into geo-graphic functions.  Perhaps someone else will give it a go.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The `CacheDuration` stores the data as long as the current session is active. If I start a new session, it again downloads the tiles.

Comment: @Sâu Then you may want to look into that ``GeoGraphics`TileData`` function to see if your can store and restore.

Comment: Can you point to any links, please? I am unable to find anything. Thanks.